# Bourbaki Algebraic Structures Question 4.12 [structural features when $x \to x^n$ is a homomorphism]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Question: Let $\mathrm G$ be a group such that, for a fixed integer $\mathrm {n > 1}$, $\mathrm {(xy)^n = x^ny^n}$ for all $\mathrm {x \in G}$, $\mathrm {y \in G}$. If $\mathrm {G^{(n)}}$ denotes the set of $\mathrm x^n$, where $\mathrm x$ runs through $\mathrm G$, and $\mathrm {G_{(n)}}$ the set of $\mathrm {x \in G}$ such that $\mathrm {x^n = e}$, show that $\mathrm {G^{(n)}}$ and $\mathrm {G_{(n)}}$ are normal subgroups of $\mathrm G$; if $\mathrm G$ is finite, the order of $\mathrm {G^{(n)}}$ is equal to the index of $\mathrm {G_{(n)}}$. Show that, for all $\mathrm {x,y \in G}$, also $\mathrm {x^{1-n}y^{1-n} = (xy)^{1-n}}$ and deduce that $\mathrm {x^{n-1}y^n = y^nx^{n-1}}$; conclude from this that the set of elements of $\mathrm G$ of the form $\mathrm {x^{n(n-1)}}$ generates a commutative subgroup of $\mathrm G$.

*(See the answer below for an attempt.)*

Answer (score 0):

The identity $\mathrm {(gxg^{-1})^n = gx^ng^{-1}}$ immediately implies that $\mathrm {G^{(n)}}$(resp. $\mathrm {G_{(n)}}$) is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm G$;
Denote $\mathrm {x \to x^n}$ by $\mathrm {f}$, this is a homomorphism and hence $\mathrm {G/Ker(f)}$ is isomorphic with $\mathrm {Im(f)}$, in particular $\mathrm {|(G: G_{(n)})| = |G^{(n)}|}$;
From $\mathrm {(xy)^n = x^ny^n}$ we obtain, by multiplication on both the left and right, $\mathrm {(yx)^{n-1} = x^{n-1}y^{n-1}}$, the substitutions $\mathrm {x \to x^{-1}}$ and $\mathrm {y \to y^{-1}}$ yield $\mathrm {(xy)^{1-n} = x^{1-n}y^{1-n}}$, from which $\mathrm {y^{n-1}x^{n-1}xy = (xy)^n}$ and finally $\mathrm {y^{n-1}x^n = x^ny^{n-1}}$;
The substitutions $\mathrm {x \to x^{n-1}}$ and $\mathrm{y \to y^n}$ yield $\mathrm {y^{(n-1)n}x^{(n-1)n} = x^{(n-1)n}y^{(n-1)n}}$ from which it is clear that the set of elements of $\mathrm G$ of the form $\mathrm {x^{n(n-1)}}$ generate a commutative subgroup of $\mathrm G$.